# Named pipe buffer after process end

Tags: linux, files, pipe, c, fifo

I am creating named pipes in Ubuntu 18 and 16 environments in C language using gcc as compiler (`mkfifo()` and `open()`). One of the things I noticed that the named pipes remain in the filesystem after the process ends. My process is a endless process that runs in a `while(1)` loop because of my requirements and the only way to exit is ctrl-c or the `kill` command in linux. I might add a ctrl-c signal to properly handle these situations but this is not the question.

Given that the named pipe remains in the filesystem (for example `/tmp/named_pipe1`), do I need to check if the named pipe exists in the filesystem and delete it in the beginning of the process (because the file persists in the system), or is it redundant because even the file stays in the filesystem, it's buffer is deleted and I can use it like a new fresh fifo ? Because I don't want the fifo buffers to be mixed when I ctrl-c exit the previous run of the code and start the new one. I require an empty buffer when I restart the code.

**Note:** The system is not restarted between the runs of the process. Just the process is re-run.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Make your first function call to destroy the fifo.  You don't really care if the call fails or not.  Then call `mkfifo()`  (be sure to check the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

that first call would be to `unlink()` Here is the syntax:

```
#include <unistd.h>

   int unlink(const char *pathname);
```

Here is the description from the MAN page:

unlink() deletes a name from the filesystem.  If that name was the last
       link to a file and no processes have the file open, the file is deleted
       and the space it was using is made available for reuse.

If  the  name  was the last link to a file but any processes still have
       the file open, the file will remain in existence until  the  last  file
       descriptor referring to it is closed.

If the name referred to a symbolic link, the link is removed.

If  the  name referred to a socket, FIFO, or device, the name for it is
       removed but processes which have the object open may  continue  to  use
       it.

RETURN VALUE
       On success, zero is returned.  On error, -1 is returned, and  errno  is
       set appropriately.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

   int mkfifo(const char *pathname, mode_t mode);
```

*DESCRIPTION
       mkfifo()  makes a FIFO special file with name pathname.  mode specifies
       the FIFO's permissions.  It is modified by the process's umask  in  the
       usual way: the permissions of the created file are (mode & ~umask).

A  FIFO special file is similar to a pipe, except that it is created in
       a different way.  Instead of being an anonymous communications channel,
       a FIFO special file is entered into the filesystem by calling mkfifo().

Once  you have created a FIFO special file in this way, any process can
       open it for reading or writing, in the same way as  an  ordinary  file.
       However,  it  has to be open at both ends simultaneously before you can
       proceed to do any input or output operations on it.  Opening a FIFO for
       reading  normally  blocks  until some other process opens the same FIFO
       for writing, and vice versa.  See fifo(7) for nonblocking  handling  of
       FIFO special files.*

RETURN VALUE
       On  success mkfifo() and mkfifoat() return 0.  In the case of an error,
       -1 is returned (in which case, errno is set appropriately).

Comment: Of course, if you do not want that FIFO to stay around after the process ends, then use a pipe rather than a fifo